# Probability of event occurring based on dependent events

Tags: statistics

I have a question which I'm not sure how to phrase hence i couldn't find similar questions:

Usually all the examples i find online refer to dependent events and their probability of happening based on the event they depend on.

But in my question the issue is finding the probability of that event they depend on if i know that the dependent events happened and i know their own probability.

**Example:**

- The chance if it raining today is 12%
- when it rains, there is a 60% chance of sheep roaming the fields
- on a not rainy day this probability is 70%
- when it rains, there is 14% chance of new flowers blooming
- on a not rainy day this probability is 24%
- when it rains, there is a 1% chance of an alien invasion
- on a not rainy day this probability is 11%

Now if i know that today sheep roamed the fields, new flowers bloomed, and aliens invaded, what is the chance that it rained today? is it still 12% or does the probability chance because of the dependent events?

Comment: This can't be answered without information regarding the probability of those events on non-rainy days.

Comment: @lulu i see, and if for the sake of the question the probability of each event on a non rainy day is 10% higher, will it be possible then?

Comment: If you have both sets of probabilities you can use Bayes' Theorem.  Compute the total probability of observing each of the three events, then  ask what portion of that is explained by rain.

Comment: As a test case for your calculations:  suppose the three events are each independent of the rain (so the non-rain probabilities equal the rain probabilities).  In that case, observing (or failing to observe) any or all of the events tells us nothing about rain so the answer must come out $.12$

Comment: To illustrate the effect, ignore everything but the aliens. Using your numbers:   The total probability that aliens invade is the sum $.12\times .01+.88\times .11=.098$.  The portion of that which is explained by rain is $.12\times .01$ so we divide to get that the new estimate for the probability of rain is $\frac {.0012}{.098}=0.012244898$.  Thus, just looking at the aliens, the estimate for the rain probability has dropped dramatically.  Phrased informally, seeing the aliens is very powerful evidence for the absence of rain.

Comment: @lulu thank you i understand this part now, basically it works like any other dependent events just switch the events places right? but if i calculate the same with the sheep, the chance i get is **0.104651163** which is higher than the one we got from the aliens, so how do i use all 3 conditions in the bayes' formula? or do i need to calculate the formula for each event and then sum them? average them?

Comment: As I said, compute the total probability that you observe all three events.  That is $.12\times .6\times .14\times .01+.88\times .7\times .24\times .11$ and compute the portion of that that is explained by rain (just the first term in the sum divided by the total).  You should see that, with these numbers, seeing all three events is nearly proof that it is not raining.

Comment: Note: I am assuming that the three events are independent of each other (at least, when conditioned on the presence or absence of rain).  You never stated that but I expect you intended it.

Comment: @lulu yes the events are independent of each other, and you have answered what i wanted to know, thank you! please write in into an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments:

First of all, to proceed we need to assume something about how the events depend on each other.  It can't be the case that they are strictly independent of each other.  For example:  seeing the aliens is strong evidence for the absence of rain, and as the absence of rain also increases the probability of the other two events, seeing aliens increases our estimate for their probability as well.  Best we can do (and it suffices here) is to assume that the three events are independent conditioned on the presence or absence or rain.  That is, if we are told that it is raining then seeing aliens tells us nothing further about the sheep or flowers.  Same if we are told it is not raining.  Granted, this is a somewhat technical point but these things matter.

Under that assumption:

Let $\{\phi_A,\phi_B,\phi_C\}$ be the the probabilities of the three events when it is raining.  Let $\{\psi_A,\psi_B,\psi_C\}$ be their probabilities when it is not.  Let $P$ be the probability that it is raining.  Then, by Bayes' Theorem, the probability that it is raining given that we observe all three events is $$\frac {P\times \phi_A\times \phi_B\times \phi_C}{P\times \phi_A\times \phi_B\times \phi_C+(1-P)\times \psi_A\times \psi_B\times \psi_C}$$

In your specific example that comes to $$\frac {.12\times .6\times .14\times .01}{.12\times .6\times .14\times .01+.88\times .7\times .24\times .11}=0.006160164$$

So we can be reasonably sure that it is not raining (small comfort, what with the aliens and all).